# Producing an output using the information in the column of a data (character operations (sum e.t.c))

Tags: r

I have problem with "What are the top 5 countries in research (considering Countries_Unique_Count
attribute)?" question.

The question here is asking us to output the most repetitive 5 in that column and how many times in total, using the column named `Countries_Unique_Count` header.

For example , 
( This example is given using a small portion of column )

```
{'United States': 1}
{'Brazil': 1}
{'Sweden': 1}
{'United States': 1}
{'Brazil': 1}
{'USA': 1}
{'Tunisia': 1}
{'Brazil': 1}
{'Germany': 1}
{'Japan': 1, 'Canada': 1, 'Germany': 1, 'Italy': 1, 'Iran': 1}
{'Brazil': 1}
{'United States': 1}
{'Tunisia': 1}
{'Brazil': 1}
{'Tunisia': 1}
{'United States': 1}
{'Germany': 1}
```

Expected output ,

```
Brazil -> 5
United States -> 4
Tunisia -> 3
Germany -> 2
Sweden -> 1
```

Here is my code to get that column in R. 
NOTE: `data2` excell file is not an important file, I just used it to extract the data.

```
library(readxl)
my_data2 <- read_excel("data2.xlsx")
a <- my_data2$Countries_Unique_Count
print(a)
```

Here the all column output in R

I will only share some of it due to the character limit in the post.

```
   [1] "{'United States': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   [2] "{'Sweden': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   [3] "{'USA': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   [4] "{'Brazil': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   [5] "{'Germany': 1, 'United States': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   [6] "{'Japan': 1, 'Canada': 1, 'Germany': 1, 'Italy': 1, 'Iran': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                              
   [7] "{'Austria': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   [8] "{'Poland': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   [9] "{'Tunisia': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  [10] "{'United States': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [11] "{'Germany': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  [12] "{'Spain': 1, 'Norway': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  [13] "{'United States': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [14] "{'Kuwait': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  [15] "{'United States': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [16] "{'India': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  [17] "{'Belgium': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  [18] "{'SungKyunKwan Univ.': 1, 'Sejong Univ.': 1, 'Kwangwoon Univ.': 1, 'Chungcheong College': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                
  [19] "{'R.L.': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  [20] "{'United Kingdom': 1, 'Germany': 1, 'Belgium': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  [21] "{'Spain': 1, 'Austria': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  [22] "{'France': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  [23] "{'Thailand': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  [24] "{'Australia': 1, 'India': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  [25] "{'China': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  [26] "{'Germany': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  [27] "{'Ireland': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  [28] "{'Sweden': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  [29] "{'Myanmar': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  [30] "{'United States': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [31] "{'Japan': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  [32] "{'China': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  [33] "{'Canada': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  [34] "{'Canada': 1, 'Ireland': 1, 'Poland': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [35] "{'Germany': 1, 'Spain': 1, 'Finland': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [36] "{'United Arab Emirates': 1, 'Canada': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  [37] "{'Germany': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  [38] "{'United Kingdom': 1, 'United States': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  [39] "{'Egypt': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  [40] "{'Brazil': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  [41] "{'Sweden': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  [42] "{'United States': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [43] "{'United States': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  [44] "{'Switzerland': 1, 'United States': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  [45] "{'Canada': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  [46] "{'United Kingdom': 1, 'Norway': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  [47] "{'Swed': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  [48] "{'Norway': 1}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  [49] "{'J.P.': 1, 'A.E.': 1}"
```

Here the all column from directly excell

```
Countries_Unique_Count
{'United States': 1}
{'Sweden': 1}
{'USA': 1}
{'Brazil': 1}
{'Germany': 1, 'United States': 1}
{'Japan': 1, 'Canada': 1, 'Germany': 1, 'Italy': 1, 'Iran': 1}
{'Austria': 1}
{'Poland': 1}
{'Tunisia': 1}
{'United States': 1}
{'Germany': 1}
{'Spain': 1, 'Norway': 1}
{'United States': 1}
{'Kuwait': 1}
{'United States': 1}
{'India': 1}
{'Belgium': 1}
{'SungKyunKwan Univ.': 1, 'Sejong Univ.': 1, 'Kwangwoon Univ.': 1, 'Chungcheong College': 1}
{'R.L.': 1}
{'United Kingdom': 1, 'Germany': 1, 'Belgium': 1}
{'Spain': 1, 'Austria': 1}
{'France': 1}
{'Thailand': 1}
{'Australia': 1, 'India': 1}
{'China': 1}
{'Germany': 1}
{'Ireland': 1}
{'Sweden': 1}
{'Myanmar': 1}
{'United States': 1}
{'Japan': 1}
{'China': 1}
{'Canada': 1}
{'Canada': 1, 'Ireland': 1, 'Poland': 1}
{'Germany': 1, 'Spain': 1, 'Finland': 1}
{'United Arab Emirates': 1, 'Canada': 1}
```

And as a few last additions, when I use `typeof(a[1])` , I get the output that the type is `character`.

NOTE2: I know there is some noise in several parts of the data, please act as if it is data clean.

NOTE3: Column has 1000 rows.

What should I do ?

Comment: Are the numbers important or do they change? We not just get rid of the `: 1` altogehter, unlist everthing and then just count by the column itself. Its not really clear what kind of data structure you have

Comment: I think this question would really benefit from being shortened and clarified. Could you share a small set of the data you wish to work on (e.g. `dput(head(a, n=20))` and tell us exactly the form of the expected output?

Comment: c("{'United States': 1}", "{'Sweden': 1}", "{'USA': 1}", "{'Brazil': 1}", 
"{'Germany': 1, 'United States': 1}", "{'Japan': 1, 'Canada': 1, 'Germany': 1, 'Italy': 1, 'Iran': 1}", 
"{'Austria': 1}", "{'Poland': 1}", "{'Tunisia': 1}", "{'United States': 1}", 
"{'Germany': 1}", "{'Spain': 1, 'Norway': 1}", "{'United States': 1}", 
"{'Kuwait': 1}", "{'United States': 1}", "{'India': 1}", "{'Belgium': 1}", 
"{'SungKyunKwan Univ.': 1, 'Sejong Univ.': 1, 'Kwangwoon Univ.': 1, 'Chungcheong College': 1}", 
"{'R.L.': 1}", "{'United Kingdom': 1, 'Germany': 1, 'Belgium': 1}"
) Here it is

Comment: The form is not important. I just need the output like that it could be string , int, e.t.c , e.t.c

Answer (score 0):

This data in `json` format. To make it readable you should replace `'` by `"` as follows firstly,

```
data2 <- gsub("'", '\"', data)
```

Then we can read it by,

```
library(jsonlite)


out <- do.call(rbind,lapply(data2, function(x)
             do.call(rbind,fromJSON(x))))

                    [,1]
United States          1
Sweden                 1
USA                    1
Brazil                 1
Germany                1
United States          1
Japan                  1
Canada                 1
Germany                1
Italy                  1
Iran                   1
Austria                1
Poland                 1
Tunisia                1
```

From this point on, it is nothing but the data arrangement. You can use whatever you want. I prefer the `Base R` as usual,

```
out <- rowsum(out[,1], row.names(out))
```

Finally,

```
head(out[order(-out[,1]),],5)
```

gives,

```
United States       Germany       Belgium       Austria        Brazil 
            5             4             2             1             1
```

**Data:**

```
data <- c("{'United States': 1}", "{'Sweden': 1}", "{'USA': 1}", "{'Brazil': 1}", "{'Germany': 1, 'United States': 1}", "{'Japan': 1, 'Canada': 1, 'Germany': 1, 'Italy': 1, 'Iran': 1}", "{'Austria': 1}", "{'Poland': 1}", "{'Tunisia': 1}", "{'United States': 1}", "{'Germany': 1}", "{'Spain': 1, 'Norway': 1}", "{'United States': 1}", "{'Kuwait': 1}", "{'United States': 1}", "{'India': 1}", "{'Belgium': 1}", "{'SungKyunKwan Univ.': 1, 'Sejong Univ.': 1, 'Kwangwoon Univ.': 1, 'Chungcheong College': 1}", "{'R.L.': 1}", "{'United Kingdom': 1, 'Germany': 1, 'Belgium': 1}" )
```